# MySQL query to get fields from a table where the ID exists in another query

Tags: mysql, sql

This must be fairly straight forward, as I tend to use ORMs I don't have to get my hands dirty often and am therefore struggling!

I have a database and want to get several fields from a table, that bit is easy..

```
SELECT main_table.registration_number, main_table.registered_name FROM main_table;
```

I want to filter the results based on another table, which is also easy..

```
SELECT second_table.registration_number FROM second_table WHERE this_field = '' AND that_field = '0';
```

Now the problem is I want to run the first query based on the second queries result set, I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT main_table.registration_number, main_table.registered_name FROM main_table WHERE main_table.registration_number IN (SELECT * FROM second_table WHERE this_field = '' AND that_field = '0');
```

This gives me: Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Am I handling this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select a column

> SELECT main_table.registration_number, main_table.registered_name FROM
>   main_table WHERE main_table.registration_number IN (SELECT
>   registration_number FROM second_table WHERE this_field = '' AND
>   that_field = '0');

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed to do

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery should do something like below,

> (select * from table) in subquery is not what you really need to do your
>   **so the subquery should return one column**

```
 (SELECT registration_number FROM second_table WHERE this_field = '' AND that_field = '0');
```

> You cannot have multiple columns being returned in a subquery like
>   that, doing so it will result in such error